# OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException : element not interactable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

i was doing some test and when i run a test with a [searcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaUsq.png) that i already work for and this error appear

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  ----> OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException : element not interactable
```

then i tried to run a test that i knew that worked and when it was time to use the searcher, the same error appear, it's kinda weird because i don't see any diference in the HTML code, and the searcher does work if i enter to the page manually.

this is my code to manipulate the searcher:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "input")]
private IWebElement buscadorConfig;

public ConfigurationUsuario buscarTabla(string input_search)
{
       buscadorConfig.SendKeys(input_search);
       return new ConfigurationUsuario(driver);
}
```

Here is an example of any test that use it:

```
        usuario.clickConfiguration();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        
        configuracion.buscarTabla("041097");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

And this is the HTML code for the searcher:

```
<div id="table_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
<label>Search:<input type="search" class="" placeholder="" aria-controls="table"></label>
</div>
```

To be honest i don't know why all of a sudden the searcher stop working in my test script, i have like 10 test that use it and know none of them works, i literally change anything , i don't know if the devs did but i hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a more canonical [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) as follows:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "input[aria-controls='table'][type='search']")]
private IWebElement buscadorConfig;
```